# html table format rows and columns

Tags: html, css

I am having problems with formatting a table. For some reason, the colspans and rowspans are not working and the cells are just dropped into the first row and column available. I have made column groups specifying the width of the columns. I have the code here:

```
<table class = “programs” border=“1”
    summary=“Lists the morning programs aired by KPAF from 5:00 a.m. to 12:00p.m.(central time).>
<caption> All Times Central </caption>
<colgroup>
    <col class = “timeColumn” />
    <col class = “wDayColumns” span =“5”/>
    <col class = “wEndColumns” span=“2”/>
</colgroup> 

    <thead>

        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <th>5:00</th>
            <td colspan =“5” rowspan=“4”>Dawn Air</td>
            <td colspan =“1”>Dawn Air Weekends</td>
            <td colspan =“1”>Sunday Magazine</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>5:30</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>6:00</th>
            <td col = “1” rowspan = “2”>Weekend Reflections</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>6:30</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>7:00</th>
            <td colspan=“5”> Local News</td>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“2”>Weekend Wrap</td>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“2”>Radio U</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>7:30</th>
            <td colspan=“5”>World News Feed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>8:00</th>
            <td colspan=“5” rowspan=“4”>Classical Roots</td>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“3”>What can you say?</td>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“4”>University on the air</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>8:30</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>9:00</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>9:30</th>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“4”>Animal Talk</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>10:00</th>
            <td colspan=“5” rowspan=“4”>Symphony City</td>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“1”>Word Play</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>10:30</th>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“1”>Brain Stew</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>11:00</th>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“3”>Opera Live from the East Coast</td>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“1”>The Inner Mind</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>11:30</th>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“1”> Grammar Rules!!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>12:00</th>
            <td colspan=“5” rowspan=“1”>Book Club</td>
            <td colspan=“1” rowspan=“1”>Weekend Wrap</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>



</table>
```

Comment: Your are using wrong quotes!!.. You need to use either single quotes or double quotes..

Comment: Please provide more information please. What exactly is going wrong? When I run your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/19603/) it seems as though they are properly figuring out their width, but I don't fully understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you are using bad quotes “,”. You have to use normal ones " (ASCII code: 034)